# Live table edit not only for textboxes

Tags: javascript, html-table, live

My question is about a PHP/mysql table. I need that I can change the data in a mysql table onclicking on html table.
Then I'm using Live Table Edit for my needs and that codes are perfect for textbox input, but if I want to apply that codes to upload images and radio button I've the problem to change the js code to give the var to mysql query. I try to explain better. I've:

```
<pre><td class="edit_td">
                    <img id="col_1_id_<?php echo $val0; ?>" class="text" src='data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $val1; ?>' width='60px'/>
                    <!--?php echo $val1; ?-->
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input id="input_col_1_id_<?php echo $val0; ?>" type="file" 
                        style="width: 80px;"/>
                    </form>
                </td></pre>
```

for upload images and

```
    <pre><td class="edit_td">
                    <span id="col_13_id_<?php echo $val0; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $val13; ?></span>
                    <form id="input13" method="post" style="align:left; display:none;">
                        <input name="radio13" type="radio" value="SI"> SI
                        <br>
                        <input name="radio13" type="radio" value="NO" checked> NO
                    </form>
                </td></pre>
```

for the radio button yes/no.
Then I want to send the data to mysql query using that ajax/js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".edit_tr").click(function(){
  var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  
  $("#col_1_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_2_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_3_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_4_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_5_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_6_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_8_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_10_id_"+ID).hide();
  $("#col_14_id_"+ID).hide();
  
  $("#input_col_1_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_2_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_3_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_4_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_5_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_6_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_8_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_10_id_"+ID).show();
  $("#input_col_14_id_"+ID).show();
  
 }).change(function(){
  var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  
  var var1="data:image/gif;base64,"+"/9j/4AAQSk....."
  //document.getElementById("#input_col_1_id_"+ID).src;
  var var2=$("#input_col_2_id_"+ID).val();
  var var3=$("#input_col_3_id_"+ID).val();
  var var4=$("#input_col_4_id_"+ID).val();
  var var5=$("#input_col_5_id_"+ID).val();
  var var6=$("#input_col_6_id_"+ID).val();
  var var8=$("#input_col_8_id_"+ID).val();
  var var10=$("#input_col_10_id_"+ID).val();
  var var14=$("#input_col_14_id_"+ID).val();
  
  var dataString = 
   'val0='+ ID 
   +'&val1='+var1
   +'&val2='+var2
   +'&val3='+var3
   +'&val4='+var4
   +'&val5='+var5
   +'&val6='+var6
   +'&val8='+var8
   +'&val10='+var10
   +'&val14='+var14
  ;
   
  $("#col_2_id_"+ID).html('<img src="./img/load.gif" />'); // Loading image

  //definiamo quali campi sono obbligatori e li inviamo a mysql
  if(
   //var1.length>0&& 
   var2.length>0
   //&&var3.length>0 
   //&&var4.length>0 
   &&var5.length>0
   &&var6.length>0 
   &&var8.length>0
   &&var10.length>0
   //&&var14.length>0
  ){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "query_update.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    //visualizza a video i cambiamenti
    //vanno messi tutti i campi variabili
    success: function(html) {
     $("#col_1_id_"+ID).html('<img src=var1 />');
     $("#col_2_id_"+ID).html(var2);
     $("#col_3_id_"+ID).html(var3);
     $("#col_4_id_"+ID).html(var4);
     $("#col_5_id_"+ID).html(var5);
     $("#col_6_id_"+ID).html(var6);
     $("#col_8_id_"+ID).html(var8);
     $("#col_10_id_"+ID).html(var10);
     $("#col_14_id_"+ID).html(var14);
    }
   });
  }else{
   alert('Immettere tutti i dati obbligatori...');
  }

 });

 // Edit input box click action
 $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
  return false
 });

 // Outside click action
 $(document).mouseup(function(){
  $(".editbox").hide();
  $(".text").show();
 });

});
```

so, what I need to change on that code to use radio and upload img function?
I really can't understand how modify that js code.

Answer (score 0):

File upload through AJAX is possible with `formdata` object as per XHR2. Code is to be changed as below

```
var dataString = new FormData();
dataString.append("userfile", $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]);
dataString.append("val0", ID);
dataString.append("val2", var2);
dataString.append("val3", var3);
.
.
.
```

But this is accepted in modern browsers such as  IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+

Comment: Thank you so much Thanga for ur quick reply, but i've a doubt. You don't think i'm wrong at  var var1="data:image/gif;base64,"+"/9j/4AAQSk....." line? i don't really understand how assign the input-file to the variable

Comment: Yes  that line has to be removed. The file content will be assigned directly using the statement `dataString.append("userfile", $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]);`

Comment: I've done `.....change(function(){
  
  var dataString = new FormData();
  dataString.append("val0", ID);
  dataString.append("userfile", $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]);
  dataString.append("val2", var2);
  dataString.append("val3", var3);
  dataString.append("val4", var4);
  dataString.append("val5", var5);
  dataString.append("val6", var6);
  dataString.append("val8", var8);
  dataString.append("val10", var10);
   
  $("#col_2_id_"+ID).html('<img src="./img/load.gif" />'); // Loading image...` but not work... dunno

Comment: when i upload an image or i change the value of one of the textboxes, the changes don't goes on scren with success: function(html) {... function and, of coarse, nothing goes to mysql db. But no message appear on screen, symply it's like the variables don't get the value of the <input>

Comment: You still need this statements `var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  var var2=$("#input_col_2_id_"+ID).val();
  var var3=$("#input_col_3_id_"+ID).val();
  var var4=$("#input_col_4_id_"+ID).val();
  var var5=$("#input_col_5_id_"+ID).val();
  var var6=$("#input_col_6_id_"+ID).val();
  var var8=$("#input_col_8_id_"+ID).val();
  var var10=$("#input_col_10_id_"+ID).val();
  var var14=$("#input_col_14_id_"+ID).val();`

Comment: Sorry Thanga... i think i can't explain well myself and problem too.... using dataString.append against "+'&val1='+var1" for create datastring, the script interrupt itself. It look like he try to search the new value from input-file or input-textbox but it can't take it to give it to the datastring. This js, has u can understand, better than me, when i click on a tr row get hide the span and made visible the <input>, then read the new value on textbox and build a datastring composed by var+value to a query_update.php. The problem are inputs different from type="text"